# How can I update my chat window when a new message is received on Android using Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase

I'm developing an Android app which has chat functionality between users, and I'd like to update the chat when a new message is received.

I can already receive messages using the FirebaseMessagingService class, however, I can't figure out how to update my chat activity. The problem I'm running into is I want it to update the chat activity when I get a message, but I don't know how I can check if the chat activity is running.

How can I check if the chat activity is running and then update it?

Thanks.

Comment: If you consider at some point to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the way I'd think about it is in layers:

1. The `Service` layer will be responsible for ingesting messages and then handling them, in this case, probably inserting into a persistence layer.
2. The `Persistence` layer will be responsible for holding all historical messages in an organized way (by conversation, or some other filter)
3. The `ViewModel` layer will handle acquiring the messages from the `Persistence` layer and sending those to the UI to display
4. The `UI` layer will receive "updates" from the `ViewModel` layer and update itself accordingly.

Now, to accomplish the real-time behavior you are wanting, You'll want to look into a few of Google's new Architecture Components that I'll link here:

[ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) - Promotes MVVM architecuture (good separation of logic) and persists through lifecycle changes. Used in your `ViewModel` layer (duh!).

[Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/) - Simple, easy-to-use wrapper for SQLite, written by the Google team. This will be used in your `Persistence` layer.

[LiveData](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/arch/livedata) - Observable data object wrapper, basically any time the underlying data changes, LiveData will notify it's observer so that it can act upon the new data. This will give you the real-time aspect you're looking for. And by the way, Room is fully compatible with LiveData, so anytime your DB experiences a change, you can act on that immediately.

There are tons of good examples floating around the interwebs for Room/MVVM/ViewModel/LiveData examples, so check one out to get started!